# How to round a value in mongodb aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have function which calculate min, max and mean of given date range from db collection. I need the min, max and mean but as rounded values.

**Sample Doc :**

```
 {
    maxspeed: 27.264,
    minspeed: 11.5,
    meanspeed: 14.407407407
 }
```

**Code :**

```
exports.findspeedminmaxmean = (req, res) => {
    var a=req.query.osm_start_node_id;
    var b= req.query.osm_end_node_id;
    var date1=req.query.utc_timestamp;
    var num1=parseInt(a);
    var num2=parseInt(b);
     console.log(a);

    speeddata.aggregate([{ $match: { 'osm_start_node_id': num1,'osm_end_node_id':num2,'utc_timestamp':{$gte:date1[0],$lte:date1[1]}}},
    {$group:{_id:"$osm_start_node_id",_id:"$osm_end_node_id",maxspeed:{$max:"$speed_mph_mean"},
    minspeed:{$min:"$speed_mph_mean"},
    meanspeed:{$avg:"$speed_mph_mean"}}}])
  .then(stable => {
      if(!stable) {
          return res.status(404).send({
              message: "record not found " + req.query.osm_way_id
          });            
      }
      res.send(stable);
      console.log(stable);
  }).catch(err => {
      if(err.kind === 'osm_way_id') {
          return res.status(404).send({
              message: "record not found " + req.query.osm_way_id
          });                
      }
      return res.status(500).send({
          message: "something wrong with name " + req.query.osm_way_id
      });
  });
 };
```

Comment: Please post the inserted image content as a JSON or text document.

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ? Also what do you mean by rounded ? Just numbers rather-than decimals ?

Comment: rounder mean if i have mean in 14.555522 i need to convert this into 15

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan : what your MongoDB version ?

Comment: mongodb version is 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On MongoDB version >=`4.2`, you can use [$round](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/round/index.html) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      maxspeed: {
        $round: [
          "$maxspeed",
          0
        ]
      },
      minspeed: {
        $round: [
          "$minspeed",
          0
        ]
      },
      meanspeed: {
        $round: [
          "$meanspeed",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5LPQmZyc9Qc)

Comment: mean meanspeed is not getting round!

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan : Do you mean 14.407407 to 15 ? How can that happen ? It would round anything above or equal to `.5` to next integer..

Comment: what if the number is above .5 ?

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan : It should work - you can minspeed example in link provided, can you give me sample of where it's failing in shared playground link..

Comment: please check :[{"_id":5212739096,"maxspeed":27,"minspeed":12,"meanspeed":14.975308641975309}]

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan : Check this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ZeXxUqCKVB , I don't see any issue here. You might be doing something wrong in your code, Did you check whether you're passing correct field names, also those values of fields are valid types ?

Comment: now check my code again ` speeddata.aggregate([{ $match: { 'osm_start_node_id': num1,'osm_end_node_id':num2,'utc_timestamp':{$gte:date1[0],$lte:date1[1]}}},
    {$group:{_id:"$osm_start_node_id",_id:"$osm_end_node_id",maxspeed:{$max:{$round:["$speed_mph_mean",0]}},
    minspeed:{$min:{$round:["$speed_mph_mean",0]}},
    meanspeed:{$avg:{$round:["$speed_mph_mean",0]}}}}])`

Comment: check the query

Comment: @MuhammadAhsan : Ok it doesn't work like the way you're doing you can't using `$round` in group additionally you need to use `$round` on result of `$avg` not before doing it, plus why do you've two `_id`'s in query, Anyway check this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GyDTXxmG4qg